# Angular material getting colors based on theme

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am trying to style my own components i have 2 themes defined each in its own style file

Dark theme

```
@use "@angular/material" as mat;

@include mat.core();

$dark-theme: mat.define-dark-theme(
 // Removed for brevity
);

@include mat.core-theme($dark-theme);
@include mat.all-component-themes($dark-theme);
```

Light Theme

```
@use "@angular/material" as mat;

@include mat.core();

$light-theme: mat.define-light-theme(
 // Removed for brevity
);

@media (prefers-color-scheme: light) {
  @include mat.core-color($light-theme);
}
```

I am trying to get a primary color from each themes is there a shorthand solution to this. I don't understand material styling that much.

```
@use "@angular/material" as mat;
@use "../../../styles/variables.scss" as vars;
@use "../../../styles/light-theme.scss" as light;
@use "../../../styles/dark-theme.scss" as dark;

$type: mat.get-theme-type(dark.$dark-theme);

$primary-light: mat.get-theme-color(light.$light-theme, primary, default);
$primary-dark: mat.get-theme-color(dark.$dark-theme, primary, default);

$primary: if($type == dark, $primary-light, $primary-dark);

input::placeholder {
  color: $primary;
}
```